# Discord.js not working as intended on node

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

---

Im trying to do the catch the error bit as im posting this and where the closed bracket is behind the period behind the catch command im getting the red line and a expression expected, Any help?

```
client.on('message', message => { 

        let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');
    
        switch (args[0]) {
            case 'warn':
            if(!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR'))return message.reply('You dont have the right position to warn...')
            if (!args[1]) message.channel.send('You need to specify a person!')
            const user = message.mentions.users.first();

            if (user) {
                const member = message.guild.member(user);
                 message.channel.send(`${member} Has been warned, Contact the moderator for reasoning and apeal...`);
            }).catch((err) => {
            return message.channel.send('An error occured...')
            })
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

`.catch()` Is used for promises, In your example you try to error handle an if statement (which does not return promises) However `message.channel.send()` **does** return a promise. Try this

```
message.channel.send(...).catch(err => {
   if (err) console.error(err)
   // Your code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this answers your question

```js
try
{
  if (user) {
     const member = message.guild.member(user);
     message.channel.send(`${member} Has been warned, Contact the moderator for reasoning and apeal...`);
    }

}
catch
{ 
  return message.channel.send('An error occured...')
}
```

Comment: You need to either `await msg.channel.send(...)` or add a `.catch()` statement to `.send()` and drop the try/catch, otherwise the error will not be caught.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
client.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');
    switch (args[0]) {
         case 'warn':
              if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return message.reply('You dont have the right position to warn...')
              if (!args[1]) message.channel.send('You need to specify a person!')
              const user = message.mentions.users.first();

              if (user) {
                   const member = message.guild.member(user);
                   message.channel.send(`${member} Has been warned, Contact the moderator for reasoning and apeal...`);
              }
    }
}).catch((err) => {
     return message.channel.send('An error occured...')
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).